# How can i write my custom link extractor in scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to write my custom scrapy link extractor for extracting links.

The scrapy documentation says it has two built-in extractors.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

But i haven't seen any code example of how can i implement by custom link extractor, can someone give some example of writing custom extractor?

Comment: What do you want to do differently to the built-in extractors, and what have you tried? :)

Comment: I just want to have that separate . even though it may do exactly the saem thing as SgmlLinkextractor. i want to have it sepparate. i don't know where to start. i mean where to define the class and how to call it

Answer (score 7):

This is the example of custom link extractor

```
class RCP_RegexLinkExtractor(SgmlLinkExtractor):
    """High performant link extractor"""

    def _extract_links(self, response_text, response_url, response_encoding, base_url=None):
        if base_url is None:
            base_url = urljoin(response_url, self.base_url) if self.base_url else response_url

        clean_url = lambda u: urljoin(base_url, remove_entities(clean_link(u.decode(response_encoding))))
        clean_text = lambda t: replace_escape_chars(remove_tags(t.decode(response_encoding))).strip()

        links_text = linkre.findall(response_text)
        urlstext = set([(clean_url(url), clean_text(text)) for url, _, text in links_text])

        return [Link(url, text) for url, text in urlstext]
```

Usage

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        RCP_RegexLinkExtractor(
            allow=(r"epolls/2012/president/[a-z]{2}/[a-z]+_romney_vs_obama-[0-9]{4}\.html"),
            # Regex explanation:
            #     [a-z]{2} - matches a two character state abbreviation
            #     [a-z]*   - matches a state name
            #     [0-9]{4} - matches a 4 number unique webpage identifier

            allow_domains=('realclearpolitics.com',),
        ),
        callback='parseStatePolls',
        # follow=None, # default 
        process_links='processLinks',
        process_request='processRequest',
    ),
)
```

have a look at here https://github.com/jtfairbank/RCP-Poll-Scraper

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time to find recent examples for this, so I decided to post my walkthrough of the process of writing a custom link extractor.

#### The reason why I decided to create a custom link extractor

I had a problem with crawling a website that had href urls that had spaces, tabs and line breaks, like such:

```
<a href="
       /something/something.html
         " />
```

Supposing the page that had this link was at:

http://example.com/something/page.html

Instead of transforming this href url into:

http://example.com/something/something.html

Scrapy transformed it into:

http://example.com/something%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/something/something.html%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20

And this was causing an infinite loop, as the crawler would go deeper and deeper on those badly interpreted urls.

I tried to use the `process_value` and `process_links` params of `LxmlLinkExtractor`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002910/links-with-space-before-and-after-are-not-parsed-correctly) without luck, so I decided to patch the method that processes relative urls.

#### Finding the original code

At the current version of Scrapy (1.0.3), the recommended link extractor is the `LxmlLinkExtractor`.

If you want to extend `LxmlLinkExtractor`, you should check out how the code goes on the Scrapy version that you are using.

You can probably open your currently used scrapy code location by running, from the command line (on OS X):

```
open $(python -c 'import site; print site.getsitepackages()[0] + "/scrapy"')
```

In the version that I use (1.0.3) the code of `LxmlLinkExtractor` is in:

```
scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py
```

There I saw that the method I needed to adapt was `_extract_links()` inside `LxmlParserLinkExtractor`, that is then used by `LxmlLinkExtractor`.

So I extended `LxmlLinkExtractor` and `LxmlParserLinkExtractor` with slightly modified classes called `CustomLinkExtractor` and `CustomLxmlParserLinkExtractor`. The single line I modified is commented out.

```
# Import everything from the original lxmlhtml
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import *
_collect_string_content = etree.XPath("string()")

# Extend LxmlParserLinkExtractor
class CustomParserLinkExtractor(LxmlParserLinkExtractor):

    def _extract_links(self, selector, response_url, response_encoding, base_url):
        links = []
        for el, attr, attr_val in self._iter_links(selector._root):

            # Original method was:
            # attr_val = urljoin(base_url, attr_val)
            # So I just added a .strip()

            attr_val = urljoin(base_url, attr_val.strip())

            url = self.process_attr(attr_val)
            if url is None:
                continue
            if isinstance(url, unicode):
                url = url.encode(response_encoding)
            # to fix relative links after process_value
            url = urljoin(response_url, url)
            link = Link(url, _collect_string_content(el) or u'',
                nofollow=True if el.get('rel') == 'nofollow' else False)
            links.append(link)

        return unique_list(links, key=lambda link: link.url) \
                if self.unique else links


# Extend LxmlLinkExtractor
class CustomLinkExtractor(LxmlLinkExtractor):

    def __init__(self, allow=(), deny=(), allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(), restrict_xpaths=(),
                 tags=('a', 'area'), attrs=('href',), canonicalize=True,
                 unique=True, process_value=None, deny_extensions=None, restrict_css=()):
        tags, attrs = set(arg_to_iter(tags)), set(arg_to_iter(attrs))
        tag_func = lambda x: x in tags
        attr_func = lambda x: x in attrs

        # Here I replaced the original LxmlParserLinkExtractor with my CustomParserLinkExtractor
        lx = CustomParserLinkExtractor(tag=tag_func, attr=attr_func,
            unique=unique, process=process_value)

        super(LxmlLinkExtractor, self).__init__(lx, allow=allow, deny=deny,
            allow_domains=allow_domains, deny_domains=deny_domains,
            restrict_xpaths=restrict_xpaths, restrict_css=restrict_css,
            canonicalize=canonicalize, deny_extensions=deny_extensions)
```

And when defining the rules, I use `CustomLinkExtractor`:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Rule


rules = (

    Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(canonicalize=False, allow=[('^https?\:\/\/example\.com\/something\/.*'),]), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found LinkExtractor examples also at
https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples
and 
https://github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples

(edited after people could not find the required info at the links above)

more precisely at https://github.com/geekan/scrapy-examples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=linkextractors&type=Code and https://github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=linkextractors

Comment: Hi @iammyr, I couldn't find examples of custom link extractors on the mentioned links... Are you sure they are there? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @IvanChaer thanks for pointing that out. I've added more precise links now that point directly to the requested info. I have no connection with those repos, just thought they could help others as they helped myself ;)

Comment: I think the OP was referring to creating a link extractor, and not simply using one.