# Scrapy python : unicode links error

Tags: python, scrapy

link encoding

when scraping a site scrapy extracts links containing &amd and throws excption:
Do not instantiate Link objects with unicode urls. Assuming utf-8 encoding (which could be wrong) so how can i fix this error?

Comment: Any example would help much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this character `→` inserted on some links. I found [this related commit](https://github.com/stav/scrapy/commit/126a0447eaf3e6a86a7d26f9febfbc37bcb87c3e) on github and than used [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815347/how-can-i-write-my-custom-link-extractor-in-scrapy-python) to write a file `link_extractors.py` with:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url


class CustomLinkExtractor(SgmlLinkExtractor):
"""Need this to fix the encoding error."""

    def extract_links(self, response):
        base_url = None
        if self.restrict_xpaths:
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            base_url = get_base_url(response)
            body = u''.join(f for x in self.restrict_xpaths
                           for f in hxs.select(x).extract())
            try:
                body = body.encode(response.encoding)
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                body = body.encode('utf-8')
        else:
            body = response.body

        links = self._extract_links(body, response.url, response.encoding, base_url)
        links = self._process_links(links)
        return links
```

Afterwards I used it in my `spiders.py`:

```
rules = (
    Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(allow=('/gp/offer-listing*', ),
                           restrict_xpaths=("//li[contains(@class,'a-last')]/a", )),
         callback='parse_start_url', follow=True,

         ),
)
```