# Links with space before and after are not parsed correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a website I'm crawling which has a white space before and after the URL

```
<a href="   /c/96894   ">Test</a>
```

Instead of crawling this:

```
http://www.stores.com/c/96894/
```

it crawls this:

```
http://www.store.com/c/%0A%0A/c/96894%0A%0A
```

Moreover, it causes an infinite loop for links that contain the same link like this:

```
http://www.store.com/cp/%0A%0A/cp/96894%0A%0A/cp/96894%0A%0A
```

Any white space(`\r`, `\n`, `\t` and space) before and after the the URL is ignored by all browsers. How do I go about trimming the whitespace of the crawled URLs?

Here's my code.

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website

class StoreSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "cpages"
    allowed_domains = ["www.store.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.sore.com",]

    rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/c/', ),deny=('grid=false', 'sort=', 'stores=', '\|\|', 'page=',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True, process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow],),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('grid=false', 'sort=', 'stores=', '\|\|', 'page='))),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['anchor'] = response.meta.get('link_text')
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: show some of your code. you can use `re/string replace` for your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used process_value=cleanurl in my LinkExtractor instance

```
def cleanurl(link_text):
    return link_text.strip("\t\r\n ")
```

The code if anyone runs into the same problem:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class storeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "cppages"
    allowed_domains = ["www.store.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.store.com",]

    def cleanurl(link_text):
        return link_text.strip("\t\r\n '\"")

    rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/cp/', ),deny=('grid=false', 'sort=', 'stores=', r'\|\|', 'page=',), process_value=cleanurl)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True, process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow],),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/cp/', '/browse/', ),deny=('grid=false', 'sort=', 'stores=', r'\|\|', 'page='), process_value=cleanurl)),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['anchor'] = response.meta.get('link_text')
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            item['robots'] = site.select('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the white space with `''` like,

```
url = response.url
item['url'] = url.replace(' ', '')
```

Or, using regular expression,

```
import re
url = response.url
item['url'] = re.sub(r'\s', '', url)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  It's not the parsed info that's the problem, but the way that scrapy crawls the relative spaced URLs.